# I want to write the logs for users info, page navigation in drupal 7

Tags: nodes

I want to write the logs for users info, page navigation in drupal 7. 
For example: from the time the user log in what actions he has performed, pages visited

Is there any module available? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User log in/out is always logged. Switch on the statistics core module for page view statistics. If you need more details google analytics is very handy (or Piwik if you don't trust google).

Comment: I have installed and  enable the module. but not able to see the logs. please tell me how should i  see the logs. I have checked in "reports" but not able to see.

Comment: You can filter the log entries by severity and topic. Look at the topics you should find somehting related to user. I'm not sure for the statistics as far as I can remember it adds it's own reports. May you didn't open any content so far, so the logs are still empty?